# LINQ to SQL: How to write a 'Like' select?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I've got the following SQL:

```
select * from transaction_log where stoptime like '%2008%'
```

How do I write this in LINQ to SQL syntax?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to use the literal method, it's like this:

```
var query = from l in transaction_log
            where SqlMethods.Like(l.stoptime, "%2008%")
            select l;
```

Another option is:

```
var query = from l in transaction_log
        where l.stoptime.Contains("2008")
        select l;
```

If it's a DateTime:

```
var query = from l in transaction_log
        where l.stoptime.Year = 2008
        select l;
```

That method is in the **System.Data.Linq.SqlClient** namespace

Comment: cool. I'm off and running. I did have to typecast "stoptime" to a DateTime in order to access the Year property, but no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

```
from x in context.Table where x.Contains("2008") select x
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this results in the proper Sql.  You'd have to profile it to see.

Answer (score 1):

If stoptime data type is string, you can use .Contains() function, and also .StartsWith() and .EndsWith().

Answer (score 0):

If you use the contains to method then you are doing a LIKE '%somestring%'. If you use a startswith method then it is the same as 'somestring%'. Finally, endswith is the same as using '%somestring'.

To summarize, contains will find any pattern in the string but startswith and endswith will help you find matches at the beginning and end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

The really interesting point is, that .NET creates queries like "Select * from table where name like '%test%'" when you use "from x in context.Table where x.Contains("test") select x" which is quite impressing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks--good answers.

This is, in fact, a DateTime type; I had to typecast "stoptime" as:

```
var query = from p in dbTransSummary.Transaction_Logs
    where ( (DateTime) p.StopTime).Year == dtRollUpDate.Year
    select
```

Minor point. It works great!